# Python Selenium: Using css, how do I make an if else statement?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to make an if else that checks whether the css exists.

If the first css doesnt exist, it should click on the second css.

This is what I have:

```
    
#IF STATEMENT
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality').click()
 
#ELSE STATEMENT
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality').click()
```

What I tried:

```
if is_element_exist(driver, '.GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality''):
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality').click()

else:
      driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality').click()
```

Doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What if they both don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality,.GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality").click()
except:
    pass
```

Why not just use ,(OR) to check for either.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below and confirm.

Get the **Element** in a **List** and check if the **List** is `Empty or not`. if the Length of the List is `0`, the statements in the `else block` will be exceuted.

```
if len([driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality")]) > 0:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GA_Track_Action_Download-FullHD-1080p > .movieQuality").click()

else:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `if-else` block use a `try-except{}` block and catch the exception to invoke the click on the second element as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".GA_Track_Action_Download-4K-2160p > .movieQuality").click()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```